# XeLaTeX + cleveref + cyrillic fonts = Command unavailable

Tags: xetex, cleveref, font-encodings

I'm trying to write a document in Ukrainian, but somehow I can't use cleveref package anymore.

Here is my example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{ukrainian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage[backend=biber,language=ukrainian,autolang=other]{biblatex}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif} 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\cyrr}{р}
\renewcommand{\cyro}{о}
\renewcommand{\cyrz}{з}
\renewcommand{\cyrd}{д}

\usepackage[ukrainian]{cleveref}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\section{Підсумки}
\label{sec:summary}
\cref{sec:summary}
\end{document}
```

This document compiles for me, because cref generates label "розд. 1".

But if I remove silly \renewcommand{cyrd}, I get following error:

```
<long log>
(./test.out) (./test.out)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-ascii-print.def)

! LaTeX Error: Command \cyrd unavailable in encoding TU.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.24 \cref{sec:summary}

No pages of output.
```

What would be the proper way to make cleveref work?

Comment: The `xecyr` package should help. I don't know if it's the proper fix though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look in `cleveref.sty` for `ukrainian`, you see

```
\DeclareOption{ukrainian}{%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \def\crefrangeconjunction@preamble{--}%
    \def\crefrangepreconjunction@preamble{}%
    \def\crefrangepostconjunction@preamble{}%
    \def\crefpairconjunction@preamble{ \cyrii\nobreakspace}%
    \def\crefmiddleconjunction@preamble{, }%
    \def\creflastconjunction@preamble{ \cyrii\nobreakspace}%
    \def\crefpairgroupconjunction@preamble{ \cyrt\cyra\nobreakspace}%
    \def\crefmiddlegroupconjunction@preamble{, }%
    \def\creflastgroupconjunction@preamble%
      {, \cyra\ \cyrt\cyra\cyrk\cyro\cyrzh\nobreakspace}%
 %
    \Crefname@preamble{equation}%
      {\CYRF\cyro\cyrr\cyrm\cyru\cyrl\cyra}%
      {\CYRF\cyro\cyrr\cyrm\cyru\cyrl\cyri}%
    \Crefname@preamble{figure}%
      {\CYRR\cyri\cyrs\cyru\cyrn\cyro\cyrk}%
      {\CYRR\cyri\cyrs\cyru\cyrn\cyrk\cyri}%
    \Crefname@preamble{table}%
      {\CYRT\cyra\cyrb\cyrl\cyri\cyrc\cyrya}%
      {\CYRT\cyra\cyrb\cyrl\cyri\cyrc\cyrii}%
    [...]
```

and there is no direct support for Cyrillic input (the same would happen for Russian).

Using `xecyr` *might* solve the issue, but it could also do more damage.

I massaged `xecyr.sty` to become compatible with the newer TU encoding mechanism. Save the following in the working directory (or wherever TeX is able to find it) as `tucyradd.def`

```
% taken from xecyr.sty
%%% Cyrillic letter TeX definitions for XeTeX (and LuaTeX)
% This definition set is complete for all Slavic Cyrillic 
% languages (Russian, Ukrainian, Belorussian,
% Rusyn, Serbian, Macedonian and Bulgarian alphabets).
%
% It has not been confirmed as complete, but might be, for those
% non-Slavic Cyrillic languages:
% Ossetian, Khalka, Buryat, Kalmyk, Kyrgyz, Tatar, Uzbek
% Azerbaijani, Kazakh, Abkhaz, Chukchi.

%%% Part I
%%% Cyrillic letters defined as a continuous stretch 
%%% in Unicode and most common 8-bit encodings which define them:

\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRA}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0410}        % А
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyra}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0430}        % а
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRB}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0411}        % Б
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrb}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0431}        % б
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRV}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0412}        % В 
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrv}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0432}        % в
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRG}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0413}        % Г
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrg}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0433}        % г
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRD}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0414}        % Д
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrd}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0434}        % д
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRE}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0415}        % Е 
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyre}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0435}        % е
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRZH}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0416}       % Ж 
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrzh}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0436}       % ж
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRZ}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0417}        % З
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrz}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0437}        % з
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRI}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0418}        % И
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyri}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0438}        % и
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRISHRT}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0419}    % Й
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrishrt}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0439}    % й
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRK}\UnicodeEncodingName{"041A}        % К
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrk}\UnicodeEncodingName{"043A}        % к
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRL}\UnicodeEncodingName{"041B}        % Л
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrl}\UnicodeEncodingName{"043B}        % л 
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRM}\UnicodeEncodingName{"041C}        % М
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrm}\UnicodeEncodingName{"043C}        % м
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRN}\UnicodeEncodingName{"041D}        % Н
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrn}\UnicodeEncodingName{"043D}        % н
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRO}\UnicodeEncodingName{"041E}        % О
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyro}\UnicodeEncodingName{"043E}        % о
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRP}\UnicodeEncodingName{"041F}        % П
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrp}\UnicodeEncodingName{"043F}        % п
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRR}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0420}        % Р
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrr}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0440}        % р
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRS}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0421}        % С
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrs}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0441}        % с
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRT}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0422}        % Т
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrt}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0442}        % т
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRU}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0423}        % У
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyru}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0443}        % у
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRF}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0424}        % Ф
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrf}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0444}        % ф
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRH}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0425}        % Х
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrh}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0445}        % х
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRC}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0426}        % Ц
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrc}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0446}        % ц
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRCH}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0427}       % Ч
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrch}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0447}       % ч
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRSH}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0428}       % Ш
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrsh}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0448}       % ш
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRSHCH}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0429}     % Щ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrshch}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0449}     % щ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRHRDSN}\UnicodeEncodingName{"042A}    % Ъ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrhrdsn}\UnicodeEncodingName{"044A}    % ъ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRERY}\UnicodeEncodingName{"042B}      % Ы
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrery}\UnicodeEncodingName{"044B}      % ы
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRSFTSN}\UnicodeEncodingName{"042C}    % Ь
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrsftsn}\UnicodeEncodingName{"044C}    % ь
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYREREV}\UnicodeEncodingName{"042D}     % Э
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrerev}\UnicodeEncodingName{"044D}     % э
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRYU}\UnicodeEncodingName{"042E}       % Ю
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyryu}\UnicodeEncodingName{"044E}       % ю
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRYA}\UnicodeEncodingName{"042F}       % Я
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrya}\UnicodeEncodingName{"044F}       % я

%%% Part II
%%% Cyrillic letters not defined as continuous stretches,
%%% but available in common 8-bit cyrillic encodings,
%%% like cp1251 and iso-8859-5, sorted by languages 
%%% they're used in for ease of checking:

% Common to many languages:
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRYO}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0401}       % Ё
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyryo}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0451}       % ё
% Belorussian-Uzbek:
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRUSHRT}\UnicodeEncodingName{"040E}    % Ў
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrushrt}\UnicodeEncodingName{"045E}    % ў
% Ukrainian-Rusyn:
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRGUP}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0490}      % Ґ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrgup}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0491}      % ґ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRYI}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0407}       % Ї
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyryi}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0457}       % ї
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRIE}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0404}       % Є
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrie}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0454}       % є 
% Ukrainian-Belorussian-Rusyn-Kazakh:
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRII}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0406}       % І
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrii}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0456}       % і
% Serbian-Macedonian-Azerbaijani:
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRJE}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0408}       % Ј
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrje}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0458}       % ј
% Serbian-Macedonian-Abkhaz:
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRDZHE}\UnicodeEncodingName{"040F}     % Џ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrdzhe}\UnicodeEncodingName{"045F}     % џ
% Serbian-Macedonian:
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRLJE}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0409}      % Љ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrlje}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0459}      % љ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRNJE}\UnicodeEncodingName{"040A}      % Њ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrnje}\UnicodeEncodingName{"045A}      % њ
% Serbian:
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRDJE}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0402}      % Ђ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrdje}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0452}      % ђ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRTSHE}\UnicodeEncodingName{"040B}     % Ћ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrtshe}\UnicodeEncodingName{"045B}     % ћ
% Macedonian:
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRDZE}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0405}      % Ѕ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrdze}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0455}      % ѕ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRGJE}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0403}      % Ѓ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrgje}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0453}      % ѓ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRKJE}\UnicodeEncodingName{"040C}      % Ќ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrkje}\UnicodeEncodingName{"045C}      % ќ

%%% Part III
%%% Non-Slavic Cyrillic letters, waiting for their experts
%%% to be confirmed as correct.
%%% From here on, we're out of the frequently used 8-bit land
%%% and into mostly Unicode territory.

% Azerbaijani-Abkhaz-Kalmyk-Kazakh-Tatar:
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRSCHWA}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04D8}    % Ә
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrschwa}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04D9}    % ә
% Azerbaijani-Kyrgyz-Buryat-Kazakh-Tatar:
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRSHHA}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04BA}     % Һ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrshha}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04BB}     % һ
% Azerbaijani-Kyrgyz-Buryat-Kalmyk-Kazakh-Tatar:
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYROTLD}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04E8}     % Ө
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrotld}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04E9}     % ө
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRY}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04AE}        % Ү
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyry}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04AF}        % ү
% Azerbaijani-Tajik-Kazakh-Uzbek:
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRGHCRS}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0492}    % Ғ 
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrghcrs}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0493}    % ғ
% Tajik-Abkhaz-Kazakh-Uzbek:
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRKDSC}\UnicodeEncodingName{"049A}     % Қ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrkdsc}\UnicodeEncodingName{"049B}     % қ
% Tajik-Abkhaz-Uzbek:
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRHDSC}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04B2}     % Ҳ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrhdsc}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04B3}     % ҳ
% Tajik-Abkhaz:
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRCHRDSC}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04B6}   % Ҷ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrchrdsc}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04B7}   % ҷ
% Kalmyk-Kyrguz-Tatar:
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRNDSC}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04A2}     % Ң
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrndsc}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04A3}     % ң
% Kalmyk-Tatar:
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRZHDSC}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0496}    % Җ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrzhdsc}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0497}    % җ
% Ossetian: 
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRAE}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04D4}       % Ӕ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrae}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04D5}       % ӕ
% Azerbaijani:
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRCHVCRS}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04B8}   % Ҹ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrchvcrs}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04B9}   % ҹ 
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRKVCRS}\UnicodeEncodingName{"049C}    % Ҝ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrkvcrs}\UnicodeEncodingName{"049D}    % ҝ
% Kazakh:
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRYHCRS}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04B0}    % Ұ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyryhcrs}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04B1}    % ұ
% Abkhaz:
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRGHK}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0494}      % Ҕ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrghk}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0495}      % ҕ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRABHDZE}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04E0}   % Ӡ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrabhdze}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04E1}   % ӡ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRKHCRS}\UnicodeEncodingName{"049E}    % Ҟ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrkhcrs}\UnicodeEncodingName{"049F}    % ҟ  
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRPHK}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04A6}      % Ҧ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrphk}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04A7}      % ҧ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRTDSC}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04AC}     % Ҭ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrtdsc}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04AD}     % ҭ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRTETSE}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04B4}    % Ҵ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrtetse}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04B5}    % ҵ  
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRABHCH}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04BC}    % Ҽ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrabhch}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04BD}    % ҽ 
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRABHCHDSC}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04BE} % Ҿ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrabhchdsc}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04BF} % ҿ 
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRABHHA}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04A8}    % Ҩ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrabhha}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04A9}    % ҩ
% Chukchi: 
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRKHK}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04C3}      % Ӄ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrkhk}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04C4}      % ӄ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRNHK}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04C7}      % Ӈ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrnhk}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04C8}      % ӈ

%% P.S. Tajik and Chuvash, while mentioned, 
%% have letters which are apparently missing and are NOT complete.

%%% Part IV  
%%% Historical letters, needed to support old orthographies.
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRYAT}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0462}      % Ѣ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyryat}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0463}      % ѣ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRBYUS}\UnicodeEncodingName{"046A}     % Ѫ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrbyus}\UnicodeEncodingName{"046B}     % ѫ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRIZH}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0474}      % Ѵ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrizh}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0475}      % ѵ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRFITA}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0472}     % Ѳ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrfita}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0473}     % ѳ

%%% Part V
%%% UNRECOGNISED NON-SLAVIC CYRILLIC LETTERS
%%% Belong to languages not mentioned herein.

\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRpalochka}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04C0} % Ӏ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRZDSC}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0498}     % Ҙ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrzdsc}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0499}     % ҙ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRKBEAK}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04A0}    % Ҡ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrkbeak}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04A1}    % ҡ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRNG}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04A4}       % Ҥ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrng}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04A5}       % ҥ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRSDSC}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04AA}     % Ҫ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrsdsc}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04AB}     % ҫ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRCHLDSC}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04CB}   % Ӌ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrchldsc}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04CC}   % ӌ

%% These are probably improperly named either in TeX or Unicode,
%% since their Unicode names and TeX names do not match.
%% TeX definitely treats them as the same symbol though.
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRMDSC}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04CD}     % Ӎ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrmdsc}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04CE}     % ӎ
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRLDSC}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04C5}     % Ӆ 
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrldsc}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04C6}     % ӆ

%% These two letters are part of proposed Unicode for Kurdish
%% and their codepoints may or may not change upon inclusion.
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRQ}\UnicodeEncodingName{"051A}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrq}\UnicodeEncodingName{"051B}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRW}\UnicodeEncodingName{"051C}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrw}\UnicodeEncodingName{"051D}

%%% Part VII
%%% PUNCTUATION AND UNCLEAR CASES
%%% Exotic (punctuation, letters...)
%%% (this list is probably incomplete)

% A dash - Defined in cyrillic.mtx to be emdash
% and should have been emdash all along.
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrdash}\UnicodeEncodingName{"2014} 

% Exotic angle brackets.
% Might still be unprintable for you.
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrlangle}\UnicodeEncodingName{"27E8}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrrangle}\UnicodeEncodingName{"27E9}

% This particular association is not certain but I guess 
% we'll hear about it when someone trips over it.
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYREPS}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0510}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyreps}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0511}

% Can't confirm those, but I'm positive the codepoints are correct:
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRGDSC}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04F6}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrgdsc}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04F7}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRHHK}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04FC}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrhhk}\UnicodeEncodingName{"04FD}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRLHK}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0512}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrlhk}\UnicodeEncodingName{"0513}

% I could not assign these in a way that would make sense,
% since I couldn't find matches in cyrillic unicode table.

%\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRNLHK}\UnicodeEncodingName{"????}
%\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrnlhk}\UnicodeEncodingName{"????}
%\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRRDSC}\UnicodeEncodingName{"????}
%\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrrdsc}\UnicodeEncodingName{"????}

% Oddities:
% I don't see a letter like that in Unicode cyrillic table.
% I've no idea what is it doing in a cyrillic encoding either.
%\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRDELTA}\UnicodeEncodingName{"????}
%\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrdelta}\UnicodeEncodingName{"????}

% Quotes
% Ligatures << and >> are working only with the last versions of "tex-text.map" 
% and "tex-text.tec" (http://scripts.sil.org/svn-view/xetex/TRUNK) 
%\DeclareTextSymbol{\flqq}\UnicodeEncodingName{"00AB} 
%\DeclareTextSymbol{\frqq}\UnicodeEncodingName{"00BB} 
%\DeclareTextSymbol{\glqq}\UnicodeEncodingName{"201E} 
%\DeclareTextSymbol{\grqq}\UnicodeEncodingName{"201C}

% To make it (and "--- -like shortcuts) work, "xecyr" must be loaded _after_ babel.
%\def\cyrdash{\hbox to.8em{--\hss--}}

\endinput
```

Then your test may become

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

% basic packages
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

% other packages
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

% these should generally be last
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{cleveref}

% additional basic settings
\input{tucyradd.def} % <--- definitions for Cyrillic

% fonts and languages
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setmainlanguage{ukrainian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\begin{document}

\section{Підсумки}
\label{sec:summary}

\cref{sec:summary}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It's possible that support for `\cyr…` and `\CYR…` is added in the standard TU encoding.

Comment: Thanks. Including xecyr helped, and as far as I understand it does basically the same as I tried to do. Would the "proper" solution be to update "cleveref" package?

Comment: @mcsim Nowadays, it's preferred not to load `xunicode`. Discussion is ongoing in order to decide for a direct support strategy.