# Ukrainian polyglossia wont make friends with cleveref package

Tags: polyglossia, cleveref

I have next setup:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex

\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}


\setmainlanguage{Ukrainian}
\setotherlanguages{english, russian}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[tbp]
        \centering
        \includegraphics{file}
        \caption{caption}
        \label{fig:tag}
    \end{figure}
        
    На \cref{fig:tag} зображено чорний квадрат.
\end{document}
```

It produces next errors:

```
polycref.tex|27 error| Undefined control sequence.
polycref.tex|27 error| Undefined control sequence.
polycref.tex|27 error| Undefined control sequence.
```

If I set main language to English it works as intended. How to fix it? I tried to find answer on texdoc but it didn't help.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/455124/2388

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's best to load packages first and then do setup.

Unfortunately, though, `cleveref` for Ukrainian doesn't work directly with Unicode, because it relies on LICR commands such as `\cyra`, `\CYRA` and so on. However, we can do the conversion exploiting the `t2aenc.dfu` file, but in reverse. I only define the simple characters.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{cleveref}

\setmainlanguage{ukrainian}
\setotherlanguages{english, russian}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}

% convert \cyr... and \CYR... to Unicode
\ExplSyntaxOn
\group_begin:
\cs_set:Npn \DeclareUnicodeCharacter #1 #2
 {
  \bool_lazy_or:nnT
   { \str_if_eq_p:ee { cyr } { \str_range:nnn { #2 } { 2 } { 4 } } }% \cyr...
   { \str_if_eq_p:ee { CYR } { \str_range:nnn { #2 } { 2 } { 4 } } }% \CYR...
   { \cs_gset:Npe #2 { \char_generate:nn { "#1 } { 11 } } }
 }
\file_input:n { t2aenc.dfu }
\group_end:
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tbp]
\centering

\fbox{This is a figure}

\caption{caption}
\label{fig:tag}

\end{figure}
        
На \cref{fig:tag} зображено чорний квадрат.

\end{document}
```

A typical line in `t2aenc.dfu` has the form

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0401}{\CYRYO}
```

so I define `\CYRYO` to be the character at position U+0401, courtesy of `\char_generate:nn`. Lines such as

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0400}{\@tabacckludge`\CYRE}
```

are ignored: only those where the second argument is either `\cyr...` or `\CYR...` are considered.

[image]

Comment: It's sad that this won't work out-of-the-box but anyway your solution works. Thank You a lot!