`cleveref` with cyrillic in LuaLaTeX
I'm trying to use cleveref with Russian language with unicode text in LuaLaTeX, and can't get it to work.
This mwe:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[russian]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  a=b \label{eq:1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  c=d \label{eq:2}
\end{equation}

проверка \cref{eq:1,eq:2}

\end{document}

produces the following error:
! Undefined control sequence.
\cref@equation@name@plural ->\cyrf 
                                   -\cyrl .

I tried using poliglossia as well, to similar effect.
Defining all the \cyr* macros like so (or like in this answer to a similar question):
\def\cyrf{ф}
\def\CYRP{П}
\def\cyrr{р}
\def\cyrl{л}
\def\cyri{и}
...

might be an option, but maybe there's a better way to do it?

Well, the best way would be for cleveref to be updated to work with unicode engines ;). No idea if that's a possibility. Short of that, you could avoid some of the work by re-activating Babel after cleveref overwrites its definitions for Russian. But that would still leave you with the rest to deal with. As a workaround, I'm not sure if it is better to define the macros as you suggest or to define the macros cleveref needs directly. Or if it makes no odds.

You could also try zref-cleveref. It doesn't support Russian at all, as far as I can tell, but it definitely has an active and interested maintainer, so perhaps there is the possibility there to add Russian. (I'm guessing you might have to be prepared to provide at least some of the translations, since a common reason not to support a language in a package is simply not knowing what would be correct in that language.)

By the way, don't use ebgaramond-maths if you need enough maths to require cross-references to equations.

The trick shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/706098/4427 (for Ukrainian) seems to work also for Russian.

@cfr Thank you! I might just try and add Russian to zref-clever. In my case ebgaramond-maths seems to be enough.
@egreg Thank you! Seems to work. Probably it should be a package of sorts, to deal with such cases.

Now there's support for Russian in zref-clever https://github.com/gusbrs/zref-clever/issues/28 . Adding support for Ukrainian should be pretty straightforward as well.
